# How do I configure a Kendo UI grid to use a DropDownList to edit a cell?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm having trouble configuring a `Kendo UI' grid to use a DropDownList as an editor. I have a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sujom/6/edit) example to reproduce my behavior. The goal is to populate the BinNumber, PartNumber and StockNumber fields once a selection is made from the dropdown. Currently I can't even get the DropDown to bind to the recordset properly. If I make a selection and move to another field, I get [object Object] in the BinNumber field. If I go back in and make another selection, the BinNumber then sticks. I have read the documentation thoroughly but I am still thoroughly confused by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the [object object] mess have a look at this [post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-with-mvvm-binding-to-the-data-value-field-and-not-the-object), there is an attribute introduced back in late 2013 dealing with this issue `data-value-primitive="true"`. In the past I just used to re-map the selection back to ds manually, but the attribute does it all for you, I tested in you jsBin and works fine.

```
  binDropdownEditor: function (container, options) {
            $('<input data-text-field="BinNumber"   data-value-field="BinNumber"  data-value-primitive="true" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataSource: viewModel.binDropDownDataSource
                });
  }
```

On change binding (please paste into your JSBin javascript tab):

```
var bins =["BinNumber:12121"];
var gridDS =  new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: function (e) {
                    e.success(bins);
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                  id:"Row",
                       fields: {
                         Row:{type:"string"},
                         BinNumber: {type:"string"},
                         PartNumber: {type:"string"},
                         StockNumber:{type:"string"}

                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 50
        });

 var  binDropDownDataSource = [
    { BinNumber: "12345",PartNumber:"P-2929",StockNumber:"S-06565" },
    { BinNumber: "23456",PartNumber:"P-2323",StockNumber:"S-956565" },
    { BinNumber: "34567",PartNumber:"P-4344",StockNumber:"S-67676" } ];

 function appendEditor (container, options) {
            $('<input data-text-field="BinNumber" data-value-primitive="true" data-value-field="BinNumber" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataSource: binDropDownDataSource,
                    change:function(e){
                                var ddldataitem = this.dataItem();
                                var griditem = gridDS.at(0); // you might need to tweak this line          
                                griditem.set("PartNumber",ddldataitem.PartNumber);
                                griditem.set("StockNumber",ddldataitem.StockNumber);
                       }   

                });
 }
var grid= $("#bins").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: gridDS,  
      scrollable: false,
      autoBind:false,
       batch:true,
      editable : true,
      navigatable: true,
      toolbar: [ {name: 'custom-create', text: "Add New Line Item"}],
      columns: [ {"field":"Row", title: "Row", width: "20px"},
                {"field": "BinNumber","title":"Bin", editor: appendEditor}, 
                {"field":  "PartNumber", title: "Part ", width: "200px",editable: false },
                {"field":  "StockNumber", title: "Stock ", width: "200px",editable: false }
               ]

}).data("kendoGrid");                

 $(".k-grid-custom-create").on("click", function (e) {
     gridDS.add({ Row:"1"});
    });
```

The observable you had plugged in is not really necessary the underling data source is already observable, I have removed it. Please consider improving following line the index won't be always 0 `var griditem = gridDS.at(0);`

Comment: thanks, I have edited the JS Bin to show both the data-value-primitive="true",and populating the other columns with the Part and Stock numbers after the dropdown selection is made here:  http://jsbin.com/sujom/9/edit

Answer (score 0):

Here's how my DropDown is setup. This is a boolean field, so you will have to adjust it accordingly to your field

```
    columns.Bound(m => m.IsInForecast).Title("Is Forecasted").ClientTemplate(

       "# if (IsInForecast == true) { #" +

                              "<select id='#= OrderId #' onchange=save('#= OrderId #'); style='Width: 80px; color: 'navy' > " +
                                "<option id='yes' selected value='1'>Yes</option>" +
                                "<option id='no' value='0'>No</option>" +

                                "</select>" +
                         "# } else { #" +
                              "<select id='#= OrderId #' onchange=save('#= OrderId #'); style='Width: 80px; color: 'navy' > " +
                                "<option id='yes'  value='1'>Yes</option>" +
                                "<option id='no' selected value='0'>No</option>" +
                             "# } #" 
                );
```

Comment: @C Sharper, Thanks for the effort but it really doesn't help me with my problem. I'm not using boolean and I am not using Kendo for MVC either. I am still trying to get the JS Bin example to work.